# Liquibase endDelimiter usage

Tags: oracle, plsql, liquibase

Trying to run this from Liquibase:

```
--changeset blah runOnChange:true endDelimiter:\n/\s*\n|\n/\s*$
DELETE MYTABLE;
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(A,B,C) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C');

DECLARE
  row_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO row_count FROM OTHERTABLE;
  IF (row_count = 0)
    THEN DELETE MYTABLE WHERE A LIKE 'BLAH:%';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But getting this error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid
>   character

Seems this works in these cases:

1. With just the insert/delete (no declare statement block) and without the endDelimiter statement
2. With just the declare statement block (no insert/delete) and with the endDelimiter statement

But it doesn't work all together. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DECLARE
  row_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DELETE MYTABLE;
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE(A,B,C) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C');

  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO row_count FROM OTHERTABLE;
  IF (row_count = 0)
    THEN DELETE MYTABLE WHERE A LIKE 'BLAH:%';
  END IF;
END;
```

or with a "/" after each statement

Comment: Thanks I was converging on doing that solution as well..  works fine.   Was trying to keep the two 'block's separate from a stylistic preference but it works well.